# How to use tiles insert attribute other than layout page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

**tiles-definitions.xml**

```
<definition name="layouts" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="onlyForViewJsp" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/view1.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="*/*" extends="layouts">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/view.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

**view.jsp**

```
<jsp:include page="./view1.jsp">
    <div>....</div>
```

How to **replace** jsp:include with tiles.

**Or** is their any possibilities to use below code inside **view.jsp**:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="onlyForViewJsp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only way, that I know for this is split `view.jsp` on two pieces (for example `view_start.jsp` and `view_end.jsp`) and in layout use `tiles:insertAttribute` three times: for `view_start.jsp`, `view1.jsp` and `view_end.jsp`.

But, let me ask, why do you need to replace `jsp:include` with tiles? Is it bring some benefits?

Comment: I want to use only tiles and not to use jsp:include